# Infinite auto scroll with dynamic content e.g. append

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

Every 5s new content added to page(div). After 15s page start scrolling down with css animation property.

What I want is that if there is content it should scroll down till the end.

Here is the example code in snippet. In this example code animation duration is 100 seconds. It's not allowed to make it 0 or -1. Also this time will be spent between top:0% and top:-170%. I like this speed ( 270%/100s ).

100s should be forever and speed should stay the same(270%/100s).

```js
setInterval(function() {
      $("#list").append("<div id='block'>Content HERE!</div>");
}, 1000);
```

```css
#list
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 -webkit-animation: scroll 100s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: scroll 100s linear infinite;
 -ms-animation: scroll 100s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: scroll 100s linear infinite;
 animation: scroll 100s linear infinite;
}

/* animation */
@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: -170%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: -170%; }
}

@-ms-keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: -170%; }
}

@-o-keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: -170%; }
}

@keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: -170%; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
</div>
```

Comment: Appears to continue scrolling at stacksnippets example ?

Comment: `scroll 100s linear infinite;` at this line 100 is time in sec. So after 100 sec passed it goes back to beginning.  I tried playing with 100s and -170% but they only changed the period time and speed.

Comment: Not certain interpret requirement correctly ? , _"it goes back to beginning"_ ? Is requirement continuous scroll ? What is expected result ?

Comment: Ah, changed `duration` to `10s` , able to "see" _"it goes back to beginning"_  Should elements remain outside of viewport if new content  stops being appended ? When to stop ? What is expected result when content stops being appended ? Should elements be removed from `#list` , or maintained within `DOM` when outside of viewport ?

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry for my crooked english. **1.** It can stop at the end of the '#list'.  **2.** When content stops being appended, if there is content that didn't appear in the screen it should keep scrolling. **3.** #list elements shouldn't be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
$(window).on("error", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  clearInterval(s);
  $("#list").stop(true, true)
});

$.fx.interval = 0;

var i = 0
, listScroll = function listScroll(elem, idx) {
  var block = elem.find("[data-index=" + idx + "]");
  block.animate({
    top: "-=" + (elem.height())                     
  }, (1000 * 100), "linear", function() {
    console.log(this, idx);
    listScroll($(this).parent(), idx)
  });
}

, s = setInterval(function() {
  var el = $("<div />", {
    "data-index": i,
    "html": "Content HERE!",
  });
  $.when($("#list").append(el), i)
  .promise().done([
      listScroll
    , function() {
        ++i;
      }
    ])
}, 1000);
```

```css
#list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 1%);
}
#list div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px;
  height: 36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="list">
</div>
```